# Align 2 divs side by side vertically centered of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two divs vertically centered based on the browsers view height. I'm looking to get these divs side by side too.

I can get both divs side by side, but can't get them down 50% of the vh. When I place them `top, left: 50%;`, they start there and then continue.

Is it possible to have the 2 vertical center and next to each other?

Here's the JSfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/wxjd5z9w/2/)

Or if it is easier, here's the code directly:

CSS:

```
html {
/*set website minimum resolution*/
 min-width: 1366px;
 min-height: 768px;
 margin:0;
 color:#fff
}
.wrapper{
 /*set div to 100% browser width/height*/ 
 /*width and height fall back*/
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 /*preferable height*/
 height:100vh;
}
.frame-work {
 /*move this div top/middle of screen*/ 
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.content {
  /*place inside frame-work side-by-side*/
  width:480px;
  height:300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
  background-color:#000
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!--100% w/h browser-->
    <div class="frame-work"> <!--container for 2 divs-->
        <div class="content"> <!--left div-->
            Lorem Ipsum Left
        </div>
        <div class="content"> <!--right div-->
            Lorem Ipsum Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: [Flexible box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) is great for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `display: flex;align-items: center;`  it is the best way to align center

```
.frame-work {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
}
```

like : https://jsfiddle.net/wxjd5z9w/9/